# Debian 11 - How to record Google Meeting audio?

Tags: debian, audio, recording, google

I'm having psychoterapy through Google Meet and would like to record the sessions for studying them later. But Google does not allows recording natively except if you are the inviter and pay for a premium account. This is not the case.

How can, then, I record both the microphone and the speaker audio of my PC on the same file, without needing to downgrade the audio quality by using a second microphone to record the speakers, like I'm doing by placing a cellphone on the room and recording through it?

Comment: Try [simplescreenrecorder](https://github.com/MaartenBaert/ssr) - it's also in the repos.

Comment: google meet has a record button that allows you to store a recording on a google drive, I think. Also, talk to your therapist about this first! I think it's a neat idea, but I know **I** overthink personally intense calls in the hours after them, and depending on what kind of person you are, you might, as well!

Comment: @MarcusMüller My therapist not only allows me to record the online sessions for my study, but for any other purpose that I want.

Comment: @FelixJN The screenshot on the link you provided has only one possible source of audio. Are you sure that I can record what both people say?

Comment: She / He's cool :) Was less about "allowing" (I mean, who would they be to forbid that? They're getting paid to talk to you :) ), more about "do you *recommend* that I go through the recordings after". But it sounds like they really endorse it! :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller He liked that I record because I can be on his position, hearing what I said, paying attention to how I said, and that way understand better myself. I already was able to notice links between thoughts by hearing me again on another moment when I was not as emotioned as when I said. Also, I can pay more attention to what he says when I'm not thinking about what to say to him next.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Noone can forbid you to record them unless they have a metal detector and use against you. But on videocalls that is impossible.

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah again, I said **nothing** about forbidding. I already clarified that.

Comment: "I mean, who would they be to forbid that?" -- I replied basically: people CANNOT forbid, even if they wanted to.

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah I tried fiddling around and stand corrected. One would need to merge the audio streams in the background and create a pseudostream that is recorded with this program. Sorry for the wrong suggestion. OBS studio seems to be able to do this (and I successfully tried it out) - but originally was created for video streaming and recording of such.

Comment: @FelixJN I don't mind recording the video together, because I can extract the audio later. If there is no better way, to record just the audio, I'll accept an answer that shows me how to record both audio sources (microphone and speakers) plus video, all in one file.

Answer (score 1):

Install [`OBS`](https://obsproject.com/) or use package `obs-studio` from repositories.

Open program and

1. under *Tools -> Auto-Configuration Wizard* , optimize for recording using lowest FPS as video is of no interest.

[image]

2. Under sources selection use `+` the audio input/output capture (I suggest pulse here). In either case use the "new" option and select the matching device.

[image]
[image]

Do **not** add a video stream - you want audio only.

3. Once set up, press "Start Recording" and ignore the warning about missing video input. "Stop Recording" at the end or use pause if need be.
4. Default settings regarding audio quality, output format and file save path can be changed under settings - maybe this will help reducing the file size, but I  did not really feel like I succeeded in doing so while fiddling around.

[image]